# pyserial issues with high baudrate FTDI

Tags: buffer, pyserial, ftdi

I have the following setup:

- A FPGA sending out data on UART at a baudrate of 3Mbps. The data transmitted is a chunk of 1024 bytes sent at a variable periodicity ranging from 20ms to 200ms. (So even in the worst case, datarate is far from 3Msps)
- A FTDI 232RG
- A piece of python running on my computer (Windows), doing basically : opening a COM port with pyserial, 3Msps, polling the in_waiting until it reaches the size of a packet (1024 bytes), formatting the packet received and print it on the screen

The script works well for low repetition frequency, but I face issues with higher repetitions (typically 20ms). When the periodicity in 20ms I eventually end up getting a buffer overflow somewhere before the in_waiting. I checked the timing of my python loop and it takes about 4ms. So it looks like there is something upstream (in the FTDI or Windows) that feeds the pyserial buffer with more than one packet within the 4ms following a packet.

I tried changing the FTDI latency in the driver (from 16ms default down to a few ms) but it does not seem to help.

I am currently clueless about what is happening. Would you have any advice about how to understand better what is happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how did u check the timing? Are the 4 ms the average/min/max? Which OS are we talking about?

Comment: nvm the OS question. Did overread the Windows part.

Comment: Hi Christian, I compute the loop time as the time difference between the moment I enter my loop (the in_waiting is at least the packet size) and the time at the following in_waiting evaluation. Since the packet length is constant and the packet is constant, my machine being not heavily loaded, 4ms is the max, with an average about 3.8ms and a min about 3.8ms too.

Comment: ahh wait. How do you define a "buffer overflow". Does data go missing? Or is it just "too much data at once"? Because this is expected as the FTDI clusters received data until enough is received for one USB frame or until a timeout is triggered. It is similiar to the Nagle algorithm for TCP.

Comment: Some data goes missing because the data I transfer is a list a 16 bits number, and I see that at some moment, LSB and MSB got "swapped" indicating a loss of a odd number of bytes (a loss of an even number of bytes would be a loss of an entire number of 16 bits and I may not catch it). I know kind of the values I expect (within a given range) so I see the loss of data when I see the "endianness change" even if what happens is an endianness change, but rather a chunk of data lost. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I would recommend to generate stub data like sequential numbers and check for every part where the loss might occur. I.e. using 16 bit data from one FTDI to another FTDI, from FPGA to FTDI, and the same with only 8 bit data. Ideally verify the data using an scope with an built-in digital analyser. Sometimes one overlooked minor things. Did you check the Windows driver settings, like buffer size etc.?

Comment: Thanks Christian for the followup. I'm sure I overlooked something. I did change the FPGA code to send out clear pattern on the data to evaluate the size of the missing chunk. I do see missing chunk of variable size, ranging in the 100s of missing symbols. I also have an oscilloscope connected, and the decoding of the UART seem fine, even if I haven't managed yet to catch on the scope a section that is missing in my program. I did reduce the latency to 1ms, increased the buffer size to the maximum, and looked to settings that could be relevant. I'm not sure how I should proceed to dig further.

Comment: I still haven't found the root cause. I recorded the data using other SW (putty and device monitoring studio) and I see the same issue, happening roughly at the same rate. So it does not seem related to the python code running on the PC. I haven't yet managed to find a way to store in the oscilloscope the failing window...This step would help narrowing down the source.

Comment: can you reproduce the behavior with other PCs as well? Does it happen with 8 bit words too? And what if you use another USB to UART converter instead a FPGA as a source?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a "loop" between TX and RX and run the following code (tested with a FT2232H, so mostlikely you need to change the identifier string):

```
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports


print([(x[0],x[2]) for x in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()])
port    = [x[0] for x in serial.tools.list_ports.comports() if "FT4Q1LJFB" in x[2]][0]
ser     = serial.Serial(port,12000000)

while True:
    t0      = time.time()
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1000):
        ser.write([1]*3000)
        recv    = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        delta_t = time.time() - t0
        counter += len(recv)
        
    print(counter / delta_t)
```

For me the following output is shown

```
[('COM7', 'USB VID:PID=0403:6010 SER=FT4Q1LJFA'), ('COM8', 'USB VID:PID=0403:6010 SER=FT4Q1LJFB')]
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
96787.81184093593
1201991.0268273412
1201197.0857713912
1201166.9350959768
1201445.4072856384
```

You will notice that it is 0.0 in the beginning. This is because I connected RX and TX after starting the program resulting in a ramping up of the received bytes. This is the "default" mode meaning 8 bits + 1 start bit + 1 stop bit = 10 bits per word which explains why "only" 1.2 Mbytes per second are transmitted.

Comment: Thanks Christian for your code. Indeed useful and even simpler in my case since I don't have TX (the FPGA sends out unconditionally on a period event). I'll test this code when I have the setup in hand (Covid home office). As far as I remember, I would say in some case, I get >3000 bytes arriving within a 4ms (at most) loop, so it would report >750kB/s (over than the 3Mbps). I'll check asap. An idea could be to just read without processing to speedup the loop and maybe see better the "burst" event

Comment: I had the chance to test your idea, but basically the result is the same as what you get. I basically get some jitter around the value I expect (which is expectable since my UART stream is periodic) and the result I get at the moment the system "goes wrong" and after is not different by more than the jitter I see when the system works. I'm kind of clue less about where things are going wrong.